# Models in $L$ are models in $V$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

It's been a while since I've dealt with something like this so I'm a bit fuzzy on the details which explains the question.

Let $T$ be a first order theory. For starters, say $T$ is finite.

Now assume $V$ is a model of ZF; and that $L^V \models "T$ has a model" (where $L^V$ is the constructible universe of $V$, and the sentence "$T$ has a model" can be written out in full since $T$ is finite.

Is it then true that $V\models "T$ has a model" ? I think it is, because as $T$ is first order, a model for it in $L^V$ will also be an actual model. If it's not true, then where does the obvious approach to proving it go wrong ?

As I see it intuitively, for any sentence $\phi$ in the language used for $T$, we will have $L^V \models "\mathfrak{M}$ is a model of $\phi$" iff $V\models$ the same thing : for the atomic formulas it comes from the fact that $L^V$ is a submodel of $V$ so the function symbols are interpreted the same way in both and $((x_1,...,x_n)\in R)^{L^V}$ iff $((x_1,...,x_n)\in R)^V $ for a fixed $R\in V$; and then the rest follows from the fact that $L^V$ is a *transitive* submodel of $V$ (for quantifications; the connectives should not be a problem).

If this is true, then how far can we go along this route; i.e. for instance can we replace "finite theory" by "recursively axiomatizable theory" (this would be about as far as we can get, since we need to be able to code "$x$ is a model of $T$" as a $\{\in\}$-sentence) ?

On the same line of ideas, I'm having a doubt as to what's necessary to prove the completeness theorem for finite/countable theories. I think that countable choice us enough but I don't recall whether it's necessary. If it's not and that completeness for these theories is provable from ZF alone then the above argument would be largely simplified; as $\omega^L = \omega$ and so proofs in $L$ are the same as proofs in $V$. But I suspect that countable choice or something in the likes of it is necessary; can anyone also put an end to this doubt ? (I'm not asking a separate question because as I pointed out the two are related - should I ?)

To sum up, here are my questions :

> Is my argument for finite theories correct ? If not, why ? And if not, does the conclusion hold nonetheless ?
>
> Can we go further than finite theories, e.g. with recursively axiomatizable theories ? If not, where does the process blow up ?
>
> What choice principle is necessary to prove the completeness theorem for finite/countable theories ? Can this help for the two questions above ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The completeness theorem only requires choice to *well-order the language of the theory*. If the language is already well-orderable, then no choice is needed. In particular, countable theories have countable (hence well-orderable) languages.

There are now two useful observations to make:

- Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a structure in $L$, and $\varphi$ is a sentence. Then $\mathcal{M}\models \varphi$ iff $L$ thinks $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$.

This is proved by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$, basically as you've said. *(Incidentally, we [do have to be careful](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0670) with stronger "obvious" statements.)*

Similarly, we have:

- The Henkin process of constructing a model of a consistent well-ordered theory is absolute between transitive models of set theory: if we do the Henkin construction in $L$, we get the same thing as if we do it in $V$.

Noting that *everything* is well-orderable in $L$ *(and $L$ is correct about well-orderings: if $L$ thinks something is a well-ordering, it really is)*, we have:

> Suppose $T$ is a first-order theory in $L$ (of any complexity and any cardinality). Then the following are equivalent: $(i)$ $T$ is consistent, $(ii)$ $T$ has a model in $V$, $(iii)$ $T$ has a model in $L$.

By contrast, if $V$ doesn't satisfy choice, there may be consistent theories in $V$ without models in $V$. The point, however, is that such theories are too complicated for $L$ to even talk about.

---

Kunen's book has a good introduction to absoluteness and arguments involving it. Incidentally, there are very very strong absoluteness principles out there - e.g. [Shoenfield absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield's_absoluteness_theorem) - which will let you do quite a bit more than may seem possible at first. *(For a silly example, Shoenfield shows that if ZFC+CH proves the Riemann hypothesis, then ZF already proves the Riemann hypothesis.)*

Comment: Ok thank you for confirming what I thought (and going further) ! However I'm surprised by what you said about $L$ and well-orderings : isn't $L$ missing plenty of subsets that might lack a minimum ?

Comment: @Max I only said that if $L$ thinks that something is a well-ordering, it is. $V$ may have lots of sets which have no well-orderings, but none of them will be in $L$: for every $a\in L$, there is a binary relation $R$ on $a$ which $L$ thinks is a well-ordering, and that $R$ really is a well-ordering (that is, every element of $L$ is truly well-orderable).

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking that if $(a, <)$ is a well-ordering in $L$ there might be subsets of $a$ in $V$ that lack a minimum; but I actually found a proof of your claim so I understand now (essentially it's the fact that ordinals in $L$ are the same as in $V$)

Comment: The completeness theorem doesn't require choice at all. Not even to well-order the theorem. It can be proved in ZF for a theory that is well-orderable, but assuming BPI, it can just be proved for everything, even non-well-orderable theories.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : well the BPI is some form of choice principle; so it's still "some choice" . I wasn't aware of that though

Comment: @Max: True. But far less than "the language has to be well-orderable".

Comment: @NoahSchweber : in Hamkins' article, the difference is that the structural induction would not work, because $M_1, M_2$ and the "larger universe" would not agree on what the set of formulas is, is that it ? (otherwise I don't really see where the proof fails, which is worrying me about my understanding of the $L$ case)